# Why is This string not changing or staying a number?

Tags: node.js

I must be tired because this is making no sense..

```
// get user input, if they enter a string,
// set result to 0 and return.
 function evalInput(_input) {
     // set result default to 0, a number
     var result = 0;    
    // make sure _input is a number
    if (typeof(parseInt(_input)) === 'number')  {
      // It is indeed a number  
      if (_input == 3) { 
        launchHelp("./Help.txt");
      }
       result = _input;
     } else {            // user entered a string
       // make sure its a number!!! 
       // was already 0, but just to make sure its assigned a number
       result = 0;  
       // surely itll be a number now            
       result = parseInt(result);
    }

    // says its a number..
    prompt("typeof(typeof(parseInt(result))) = " + typeof(parseInt(result))); 
    // now its a string again?
    prompt("typeof(result) = " + typeof(result)); 

    return result;
}
```

output:

Choice: d

```
typeof(typeof(parseInt(result))) = number
typeof(result) = string
```

I simply need result to be a type number.

i even tried assigning another variable 0 and then assigning result again. Ive tried all this and more without `parseInt()`. I used it to make sure the string was changed to a number.

```
var number = 0;
result = number;
```

My main issue is when you `parseInt("0")` it should cast 0, not "0" . this is what is happening

Comment: Have you tried Number(result) instead of parseInt(result))

Comment: same. its still a string.. I wrote this very,very, basic function a month ago in another script and it worked fine. But now it will not return a number. its an easy fix in the next function but i need to know what is causing this because its not right. no way you should even need this much code. its set at 0, and doesnt need to be even altered if _input is a string. hence the first line result = 0;

Comment: `parseInt` does not change the value of an object. It **returns** a value. **BIG** difference: `_input = parseInt(_input)`

Comment: read the code. it has nothing to do with that. initially result is declared as 0. a number, it doesn not get reassigned if the user enters say "w" at all yet it still comes out as "0" and not 0 as it   was originally declared

Answer (score 1):

Your check to validate if a string is a valid number is all wrong. It will always evaluate to true and your else block will never be reached.

```js
// make sure _input is a number => wrong!
if (typeof(parseInt(_input)) === 'number') { .. }
```

This will always assert to true because when you parse something to int that is not a valid integer, you get `NaN` aka Not a Number. `typeof(NaN)` however, even thoug not a valid number, is still a number!

If you want to check if something is a valid integer, you need to use `Number.isInteger()`.

```js
console.log(typeof(NaN)); // number
console.log(typeof(parseInt("Bogus")) === 'number'); // true
console.log(Number.isInteger("Bogus")); // false
console.log(Number.isNaN(parseInt("Bogus"))); // true
```

Comment: forget that.. the problem is  i set the value of result to 0 at the start.. when a user enters a letter, then result stays 0 yet when it is returned t the calling functiion it is now a string